# Retaining value of query generated dropdown box after submission

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I populated the options for a dropdown box using the results of a query. How do I retain the selected value after the user submits?

Here's the code:

```
$query="SELECT trainingName,trainingID FROM training ORDER BY trainingName";

$result = mysql_query ($query);
echo "<select name='training' value=selected>Training Name</option>";
$training = strip_tags(@$_POST['training']);

echo "<option>---------------------Select---------------------</option>";
while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<option value=$nt[trainingID]>$nt[trainingName]</option>";
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339225/how-do-retain-value-of-dropdown-box-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query="SELECT trainingName,trainingID FROM training ORDER BY trainingName";

$result = mysql_query ($query);
echo "<select name='training'>";
echo "<option>---------------------Select---------------------</option>";
while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $selected = false;
   // check if the current value equals the value submited
   if($_POST['training'] == $nt['trainingID']){
       $selected = true;
   }

   // show selected attribute only if $selected is true
   echo "<option value='{$nt['trainingID']}' ". ($selected ? "selected" : "") .">{$nt['trainingName']}</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
```